# Why doesn't captcha display in CI?

Tags: php, codeigniter, captcha

I've set up a codeigniter project on my apache2 linux server. First thing I want to do is to create a form which will require a captcha validation, although I have the gd image library as I've seen from `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, it still shows nothing which is what confuses me.

I've tried using a construct prior to my main function(the one with the form), in it, I have loaded the `captcha` helper as well the `img_lib` library. the img_path leads back to the root folder of the project(where I have created a `captcha` folder along with `application` and `system`)

> controller

```
public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('captcha');
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $this->load->helper('url');

}

public function Form() {



  $vals = array(
        'word'          => 'Random word',
        'img_path'      => '../../captcha/',
        'img_url'       => 'http://localhost/project/captcha',
        'font_path'     => './path/to/fonts/texb.ttf',
        'img_width'     => '150',
        'img_height'    => '30',
        'expiration'    => 7200,
        'word_length'   => 8,
        'font_size'     => 16,
        'img_id'        => 'Imageid',
        'pool'          => '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',

        // White background and border, black text and red grid
        'colors'        => array(
                'background' => array(255, 255, 255),
                'border' => array(255, 255, 255),
                'text' => array(0, 0, 0),
                'grid' => array(255, 40, 40)
        )
      );

  $cap = create_captcha($vals);
  $data['captcha'] = $cap['image'];
  $this->load->view('form', $data);
}
```

> view

```
<?php echo $captcha;
?>
```

I expect an image to pop up because I've configured it all, but it just doesn't show anything.

Comment: You getting an errors? If you had some plain HTML to your view file befoer the `php` tag, do you see that?

Comment: I don't get any errors that I see, perhaps there is a debugging method for this

Comment: make sure error reporting is on in index.php (dev mode) and then check to see if your image is atleast being generated in your specified folder

Comment: which line is that?

Comment: @Alex I switched from `-1` to `E_ALL` in index.php error reporting, still shows nothing, even when inspect the src.

Comment: does you captcha image generate in your folder?

Comment: no it does not.

Comment: And I can't possibly figure out why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply needed to change permissions to 777!

Comment: which file or folder need set permission ? `/captcha` ?
cz i got same problem, but mine, captcha is generated by daemon. Maybe cz i start xampp by root,,